Is there a way to know which GCS Bucket to use by calling some service in GCP?
Let's say I have 10 applications which need to access a certain GCS Bucket A. I will create a config file for every application with the specific information to access Bucket A in it.
Now, for some reasons, data in my Bucket A gets corrupted and I need to switch to my backup, Bucket B. In the current configuration I will need to edit every config file to target Bucket B and redeploy every application. This doesn't seem optimal and very error prone.
Is there some service in GCP (or that can be installed) that can be called to give me the current bucket information I need to access ? So that I only need to configure in my applications the access to this service and only make the switch of bucket in it.
EDIT :
I have a lot of files in my Bucket A, so reverting to an old version for all my documents would (probably ?) take up to several days. Which is why I need to switch to my backup Bucket B.

There is no such feature in GCS to change bucket(but you can store files with version. So, you can revert to working version of that file. ) Also, you can install feature flag  in your code to control from outside. Another option is you can use environment variables but in that case you need to restart your application.

I'm not looking for a feature in GCS, I'm looking for a service / API / feature in GCP that could do that. And my problem is if all or most of my documents in my bucket is corrupted. It could take up to several days to revert them to their non-corrupted state, which is time I don't have, and is why I need the switch of bucket.

Versioning is the key here.
I personally don't like GCS for managing stuff with revision. I prefer putting my config in the container, with my code and to have something consistent over the time (fast roll out and roll back).
Anyway, a safe way to use Cloud Storage is to activate the object versioning. Like this, if an object version is corrupted, you can restore the previous one easily.
But again, I prefer to keep this version history in a git, or in a container than on Cloud Storage. To be more agile and efficient (your major pain point.)

You could also imagine putting a load balancer in front of your Bucket. This time you won't directly access your object in your bucket, but you will perform a get on the load balancer URL.
If you have to switch to another bucket, change the backend configuration of your bucket to use the Bucket B instead.
Note: it's not mandatory to put the bucket public as explained in the doc, but you have to include the authorization header with a bearer access token in your GET request if you let the bucket private

I'm not sure if I fall into the case of versioning, the bucket is just here to store a file, I don't have any use case where I will update the file to a newer version. It's more of a "attacker corrupted our files" kind of thing. I just looked into object versioning and learned about the soft delete but I don't think it works either since I need to store sensitive / personnal data and need to delete it according to GDPR rules. How much time would it take to restore 200 millions files in a bucket for example ?

And I'm not sure to follow when you say "change the backend configuration of your bucket to use Bucket B instead." ? Do you mean the load balancer configuration ?

Yes, when you have a load balancer, you have a frontend (the URL/IP to reach) and the backend (the endpoint to reach). You can keep the same frontend, but you change the backend. You event could already have the 2 backend set, and change only the forwarding rule (the routing) to change the default backend to use.

And can you tell me all long it would take to go back to an older version of a file for 200 millions files in a bucket ?

Hmmm, 200 millions of file and you want to revert all of them, or to redeploy clean version of 200 millions of file in a bucket B to have a cleaner config. IMO, something is odd in the design and your app management. You should try a different approach.
